# Datagridview: How to set a cell in editing mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, datagridview

I need to programmatically set a cell in editing mode. I know that setting that cell as CurrentCell and then call the method BeginEdit(bool), it should happen, but in my case, it doesn't.

I really want that, with my DGV with several columns, the user can ONLY select and also edit the first two. The other columns are already read-only, but the user can select them, and that is what I don't want.

So I was thinking, tell the user to TAB everytime it has finished writing on the cell, then select the second cell, then tab again and it select and begin edit the next row's first cell...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Setting the `CurrentCell` and then calling `BeginEdit(true)` works well for me.

The following code shows an eventHandler for the `KeyDown` event that sets a cell to be editable.

My example only implements one of the required key press overrides but in theory the others should work the same. (and I'm always setting the [0][0] cell to be editable but any other cell should work)

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);               
    }
}
```

If you haven't found it previously, the [DataGridView FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20060818191555/https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/4/5646742C-3EB7-48F7-BFB3-CC295D618CF9/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc) is a great resource, written by the program manager for the DataGridView control, which covers most of what you could want to do with the control.

Comment: Thanks...
First i was trying to use the SelectionChange event, and doing some hard (and uggly too) work to avoid stack overflow, since everytimes the selection changes it fires again.
But now, i like the most your solution... And thanks +1 for the FAQ. I'm more used to web instead of winforms, but is good to know anyway.
Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Sort of... :) I was actually trying to update cell contents from outside of the grid that was tied to a datasource. I could put the new values on the screen, but the save button was saving the old values. I needed to put a CurrentCell before and EndEdit() after I updated the values. Your answer got me totally on the right track.  Thanks!

Comment: Avoided the need to ask a similar question - ty

Comment: +1 saved me from asking a question as well, I posted a fully functional sample as a wiki to this question using this suggested method.

Comment: @StealthRabbi thanks - I've updated the link. It's a Microsoft download, so should be stable, but then, so was the original! If it breaks again, one can find by searching for DataGridView FAQ

Comment: A document you can trust: "Windows **Froms** 2.0" -FAQ Document, 1st sentence.

Comment: @KevinDeLorey ha, never noticed that! The typo aside, it is actually worth a look :)

Comment: Thanks for the doc link, even in 2018 this doc is really useful (despite any spelling mistakes)

Answer (score 6):

```
private void DgvRoomInformation_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (DgvRoomInformation.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4)  //example-'Column index=4'
  {
    DgvRoomInformation.BeginEdit(true);   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, I would check if any of your columns are set as `ReadOnly`. I have never had to use BeginEdit, but maybe there is some legitimate use. Once you have done `dataGridView1.Columns[".."].ReadOnly = False;`, the fields that are not `ReadOnly` should be editable. You can use the DataGridView `CellEnter` event to determine what cell was *entered* and then turn on editing on those cells after you have passed editing from the first two columns to the next set of columns and turn off editing on the last two columns.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is pretty old, but figured I'd share some demo code this question helped me with.

- Create a Form with a `Button` and a `DataGridView`
- Register a `Click` event for button1
- Register a `CellClick` event for DataGridView1
- Set DataGridView1's property `EditMode` to `EditProgrammatically`
- Paste the following code into Form1:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable m_dataTable;
        DataTable table { get { return m_dataTable; } set { m_dataTable = value; } }

        private const string m_nameCol = "Name";
        private const string m_choiceCol = "Choice";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        class Options
        {
            public int m_Index { get; set; }
            public string m_Text { get; set; }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add(m_nameCol);
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Foo" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Bob" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Timn" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Fred" });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

            if (!dataGridView1.Columns.Contains(m_choiceCol))
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                txtCol.Name = m_choiceCol;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(txtCol);
            }

            List<Options> oList = new List<Options>();
            oList.Add(new Options() { m_Index = 0, m_Text = "None" });
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                oList.Add(new Options() { m_Index = i, m_Text = "Op" + i });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i += 2)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

                //Setup A
                c.DataSource = oList;
                c.Value = oList[0].m_Text;
                c.ValueMember = "m_Text";
                c.DisplayMember = "m_Text";
                c.ValueType = typeof(string);

                ////Setup B
                //c.DataSource = oList;
                //c.Value = 0;
                //c.ValueMember = "m_Index";
                //c.DisplayMember = "m_Text";
                //c.ValueType = typeof(int);

                //Result is the same A or B
                dataGridView1[m_choiceCol, i] = c;
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns.IndexOf(dataGridView1.Columns[m_choiceCol]))
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[m_choiceCol, e.RowIndex];
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
                    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the column index numbers can change from multiple button presses of button one, so I always refer to the columns by name not index value.  I needed to incorporate David Hall's answer into my demo that already had ComboBoxes so his answer worked really well.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but the proposed solutions did not help in my situation.
It was necessary to select the cell when loading the form.
This option did not work:

```
private void FOperations_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dgvOperations.CurrentCell = dgvOperations[nameof(Operation.DisplayName), 0];
  dgvOperations.Select();
}
```

If you make a cell selection in the "Layout" event, then everything is successful:

```
private void dgvOperation_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
{
  dgvOperations.CurrentCell = dgvOperations[nameof(Operation.DisplayName), 0];
  dgvOperations.Select();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but none of the answers worked for me, because I wanted to reliably (always be able to) set the cell into edit mode when possibly executing other events like Toolbar Button clicks, menu selections, etc. that may affect the default focus after those events return.  I ended up needing a timer and invoke.  The following code is in a new component derived from DataGridView.  This code allows me to simply make a call to `myXDataGridView.CurrentRow_SelectCellFocus(myDataPropertyName);` anytime I want to arbitrarily set a databound cell to edit mode (assuming the cell is Not in ReadOnly mode).

```
// If the DGV does not have Focus prior to a toolbar button Click, 
// then the toolbar button will have focus after its Click event handler returns.
// To reliably set focus to the DGV, we need to time it to happen After event handler procedure returns.

private string m_SelectCellFocus_DataPropertyName = "";
private System.Timers.Timer timer_CellFocus = null;

public void CurrentRow_SelectCellFocus(string sDataPropertyName)
{
  // This procedure is called by a Toolbar Button's Click Event to select and set focus to a Cell in the DGV's Current Row.
  m_SelectCellFocus_DataPropertyName = sDataPropertyName;
  timer_CellFocus = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
  timer_CellFocus.Elapsed += TimerElapsed_CurrentRowSelectCellFocus;
  timer_CellFocus.Start();
}


void TimerElapsed_CurrentRowSelectCellFocus(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  timer_CellFocus.Stop();
  timer_CellFocus.Elapsed -= TimerElapsed_CurrentRowSelectCellFocus;
  timer_CellFocus.Dispose();
  // We have to Invoke the method to avoid raising a threading error
  this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
  {
    Select_Cell(m_SelectCellFocus_DataPropertyName);
  });
}


private void Select_Cell(string sDataPropertyName)
{
  /// When the Edit Mode is Enabled, set the initial cell to the Description
  foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvc in this.SelectedCells) 
  {
    // Clear previously selected cells
    dgvc.Selected = false; 
  }
  foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvc in this.CurrentRow.Cells)
  {
    // Select the Cell by its DataPropertyName
    if (dgvc.OwningColumn.DataPropertyName == sDataPropertyName)
    {
      this.CurrentCell = dgvc;
      dgvc.Selected = true;
      this.Focus();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer to this. In my case, I wanted to select a specific index or item after adding a new row, but this should apply to other situations.

The cell doesnt hold the combobox controls per say. The DGV does, it holds the controls of the current cell. So you have to make the current cell the combo cell, then go in edit mode, then cast the dgv controls as ComboBox, then you will have access to the selectedIndex and selectedItem methods

```
Dim rowIndex = myDgv.Rows.Add()
myDgv.ClearSelection()
myDgv.CurrentCell = myDgv.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("colName")
myDgv.BeginEdit(True)
Dim myCombo as ComboBox = CType(myDgv.EditingControl, ComboBox)
myCombo.SelectedIndex = 3
```