# combobox inside gridview while in editmode

Tags: c#, gridview, combobox

i have gridview with Databound from database in C# WinForm Application.

now ,when cell of gridview gets in Editmode,combobox should be displayed in stead of normal textview cell of gridview.

so that user can select value from combobox.

how?

Comment: I think you can find the answer for your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814423/datagridview-how-to-set-a-cell-in-editing-mode

Comment: this might be relavent
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840341/setting-datagridview-column-type-to-drop-down-at-run-time-c-net