# Setting DataGridView Column type to drop down at run time (C#.net)

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, combobox, drop-down-menu

I have a datagridview its datasource is set to a data view -> data table and rows & columns are auto generated at run time.

```
    dtable.Columns.Add("1", typeof(int));
    dtable.Columns.Add("2", typeof(string));
    dtable.Columns.Add("3", typeof(string));
    datagridview1.DataSource = dtable;
```

I want column 3 to be a drop down type and have 3 options in it. How do I do that at run time as I only populate the grid at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add columns to a `DataGridView` programatically.

In your situation what you need to do is hide the column 3 that is generated when you bind to the `DataTable` and then add a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to the grid which has column three's name as its `DataPropertyName` property.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = "3";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

You then assign a datasource to this column where that datasource holds the three options you want to appear in the grid.

The `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` also has `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties that allow you control what gets set in the grid datasource (`ValueMember`) and what is displayed.

Comment: after addding the column to the dgv, i set its datasource to datatable, but the dropdown value does not get set when the dgv gets shown even though the Data Property Name is the same.

Comment: @jaminator so the column has a datasource, which is different from the datagridview datasource, and you have correctly set the DataPropertyName and the ValueMember properties? Once you have checked that, if it still doesn't work please add code to your question showing what you are doing.

Comment: it worked when when i added the right DataPropertyName, also setting columns Name.
            col.DataPropertyName = "3";
            col.HeaderText = "3";
            col.Name = "3";

Answer (score 0):

```
   DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbo1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
   DataGridViewRow dataGridRow = new DataGridViewRow();
   dataGridRow.Cells.Add(cbo1);
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataGridRow);
```

You create a datagridview combobox and add it in datagridview1