# How to enable editing of an entire DataGridViewRow?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am trying to put an entire `DataGridViewRow` into edit mode after a button `click` event. When I need to programmatically edit a cell I use the code below, but `BeginEdit` doesn't work with rows, it only allows one cell to be edited.

```
DataGridView.CurrentCell.ReadOnly = false;
DataGridView.BeginEdit(true);
```

How can I make an entire `DataGridViewRow` editable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814423/datagridview-how-to-set-a-cell-in-editing-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard way that the DataGridView is supposed to work ... try to make it work differently and you are in for much frustration and large quantities of code.

There are several things I can think of here:

**1) Find a third-party grid control that does what you need.**

**2) Write your own grid control to do this.**

**3) Try to make the DataGridView do what it was not designed to do.**

I am assuming by your message that you are restricted to option 3? If so, then you could try this:

- Keep a flag denoting that you are in edit mode (I *hate* flag-based programming - but sometimes there is no other easy choice...).
- When the user clicks the button, set the flag and execute BeginEdit on the cell.
- On the EndEdit, use BeginEdit to start edit of the next cell (assuming the flag is still set).
- When the user presses the Enter key, exit edit on the currenlty edited cell and turn the flag off (which should prevent any other cell from being edited).

Comment: Thanks a lot,for my student work i will prefer variant with EndEdit