# Change value in DataGridView directly

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell, windows-forms-designer

How can I change the value from all cells in `DataGridView` Windows Forms? I want to change directly in Windows Forms, like typing directly in the cell

I have a table like:

```
AA    BB    CC
--------------
1     aa    ac
2     bb    fd// I type here and change the value to kk
```

Code:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn AA= new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
MsgIDHex.HeaderText = "AA";
MsgIDHex.DataPropertyName = "AA";
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn BB= new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
MsgIDHex.HeaderText = "BB";
MsgIDHex.DataPropertyName = "BB";
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn CC= new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
MsgIDHex.HeaderText = "CC";
MsgIDHex.DataPropertyName = "CC;
dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(AA, BB, CC};
```

Should I do something with `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl`?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do, or what is not working. Do you want to be able to type into a cell on the grid? This should just work. What happens when you try?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it too clearly. Thanks to Vyktor i know that to edit the cell i should write dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true); thanks all guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do this (assuming that you want to change one value programmatically):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[RowNumber].Cells[CC.Index].Value = newValue;
```

And how to enable editing of certain cell was already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814423/datagridview-how-to-set-a-cell-in-editing-mode).

Comment: I want to change directly in Windows Forms

Comment: @UniLe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814423/datagridview-how-to-set-a-cell-in-editing-mode is'n this helping? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting the datasource to an object, then the property linked to a certain field has to have a setter in order to change the value. Otherwise it is a read only property and will be treated as such. Not sure if that helps, its a bit unclear what you are after, and what you are working with.

Comment: yes, your are correct. It has just read property. How can I change my datasource that I can read and write there?

Comment: if you are using a custom object as your data source, the property in question needs to have a setter method

public <Type> PropertyName { get; set; }

Without the setter the data binding has no way to update the value in the bound object

Answer (score 0):

```
// Retrieve the cell value for the cell in the Name column at row 4.
String testValue2 = (String)dataGridView1["Name", 4].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void UpdateDataGridView(int cindex, string value)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<int,string>(UpdateDataGridView), new object[] { cindex, value });
        return;
    }

    int selectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[cindex].Value = value;
}
```