# Pasting into DataGridTextColumn? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid and one of my columns is a DataGridTextColumn. When the user presses enter, the DataGrid takes them to the next row, in which the user can immediately start typing, and the DataGridTextColumn takes the input just fine, yay!

The problem is, after they fill out one row, and hit enter to goto the next to fill it out, THEY MUST TYPE to activate the column. It's very important that the user can just paste with CTRL+V right after they are brought to the new column, and that the pasted info will automatically activate the text column without them having to type.

How can I go about this?

Comment: do some googling .. what have you actually tried on your own.. ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datagridview: How to set a cell in editing mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814423/datagridview-how-to-set-a-cell-in-editing-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Idea is similar to **Dimitris Batsougiannis** suggested, but check **Ctrl** instead.

```
<DataGrid KeyDown="DataGrid_KeyDown"...

private void DataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl)
    {
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        if (dataGrid.CurrentCell != null)
        {
            dataGrid.BeginEdit();
        }
    }
}
```