# datagridview dont let me change the values of the celll

Tags: c#

I'm new in c# , but i can do the basics. i need to change all the values of a column and then update the datagrid. The values are in 20170202 format and i want them like 2017-02-02. the method i did works fine but when i try to set the value to the column it wont change.

here is the code:

```
private void fixAlldates(DataGridView dataGridView2) 
    { 
        string aux1 = ""; 

        for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; x++) 
        { 

            if (dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value.ToString() != null)
            { 
                aux1 = dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value = fixDate(aux1); 
            } 

            if (dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[5].Value.ToString() != null)
            { 
                dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[5].Value = fixDate(dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[5].Value.ToString()); 
            } 


            dataGridView2.Refresh(); 
              MessageBox.Show(fixDate(aux1); ----> shows result like i want ex: 2017-02-02 
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value.ToString()); ----> shows 2070202 
        }       
    } 


    private string fixDate(string p) 
    { 

        if (p == null) return "No especificado"; 
            String fecha = "" + p.Substring(0, 4) + "-" + p.Substring(4, 2) + "-" + p.Substring(6, 2) + ""; 
            return fecha; 


    }
```

sorry for my bad english , im a little bit rusty

Edit:

I fill the data with bindingSource.

```
   private void LlenarProductos(string rut)
    {

        this.rut = rut;
        POLbindingSource1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
        DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        dc.CommandTimeout = 0;
        System.Data.Linq.Table<ASE_PRODUCTOASEGURADO> producto = dc.GetTable<ASE_PRODUCTOASEGURADO>();
        var todoprod = from p in producto
                       where p.RUT == int.Parse(rut)
                       select new
                       {
                           p.POLIZA,
                           p.SOCIO,
                           p.SUCURSAL,
                           p.COD_PROPUESTA,
                           p.FECHA_ALTA_COTI,
                           p.FECHA_ALTA_VCTO,
                           p.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO
                       };

        POLbindingSource1.DataSource = todoprod; // binding source 
        dataGridView2.DataSource = POLbindingSource1; // filll
        this.dataGridView2.Columns["POLIZA"].HeaderText = "Poliza";
        this.dataGridView2.Columns["Socio"].HeaderText = "Socio";
        this.dataGridView2.Columns["Sucursal"].HeaderText = "Sucursal";
        this.dataGridView2.Columns["COD_PROPUESTA"].HeaderText = "Propuesta";
        this.dataGridView2.Columns["FECHA_ALTA_COTI"].HeaderText = "Fecha Cotizacion";
        this.dataGridView2.Columns["FECHA_ALTA_VCTO"].HeaderText = "Fecha Vencimiento";
        this.dataGridView2.Columns["NOMBRE_PRODUCTO"].HeaderText = "Producto";
        //  fixAlldates(dataGridView2); 
    }
```

Comment: do you get an error? or have you traced it using breakpoint?

Comment: the code is executed normally? also can you show us how the datagridview is filled with data?

Comment: It would be better to fix the *data* so that the fields contain actual DateTime objects instead of strings like `20170202`. All you'd need then would be to specify the correct format string for the grid column. How do you load the data? How do you bind it to the grid?

Comment: @Artiom that's what caused the problem in the first place. Instead of loading dates, the data contained a formatted string. *Don't* format the data before population. Let the format string do its job

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are telling me that i can format the column to datetime?  will it work if the comes from db without datetime format?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if the data that comes from the database is a DateTime or a number, you can use the `DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle` to apply styling, including setting the `Format` property to a format string, eg `Columns["FECHA_ALTA_COTI"].DefaultCellStyle.Format="YYYY-MM-DD"`. You won't need to convert anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It did not work, it think because it comes a a string from the db not as a datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value(v=vs.110).aspx.

***The Value property is the actual data object contained by the cell.***

So basically the line `MessageBox.Show(dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value.ToString());` is getting the value of the underlying data, whereas `MessageBox.Show(fixDate(aux1);` is actually formatting the date as you require.

You're overlooking the fact that although you're seeing the data in the grid in a specific way, you're not actually changing the data itself.

**UPDATE**

To actually edit the data in a cell see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814423/datagridview-how-to-set-a-cell-in-editing-mode)

Comment: Then how do i set the value of the underlying data?

Comment: @JoaquinMuñozBarceló you probably don't need to change the data. What is the type of the data? Is it DateTime? A string? A number?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos a string.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane using beginedit(true) after 
dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value = fixDate(aux1); 
did not work :(

Comment: @JoaquinMuñozBarceló Given that `beginedit(true)` makes the cell editable, why would you expect it to work when you doing it after trying to edit the cell?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane i tried both , none of them Works but then i realized that i have my method commented so,  sorry about that. My problem is solved.!