# How to allow edit only in specific datagridview cell?

Tags: c#

I'm trying this for but it doesnt work

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Add("TEST");
dataGridView2.Columns[0].ReadOnly = false;
```

Is there any other method?

Comment: There is the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814423/datagridview-how-to-set-a-cell-in-editing-mode I think there is no other possibility to do it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datagridview: How to set a cell in editing mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814423/datagridview-how-to-set-a-cell-in-editing-mode)

Comment: So technically it's not a duplicate but the opposite of that duplicate which will answer this question as well but is it okay to say it's a duplicate?