# How to keep a cell active (not just selected/highlighted) when you refresh a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a list of firewall rules. I have a button to update/reload the DataGridView, but I want to keep the last cell I selected active (and visible) when I reload.

With the code I currently am using it only keeps it highlighted, but not exactly active/usable. Here is the snippet:

```
int x = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
updateTable();
DataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[0].Selected = true;
```

And here's the `updateTable()` code:

```
public void updateTable()
        {
            DataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = myDLL.getFirewallRules();
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dtFirewall;
            DataGridView1.Columns["OriginalIndex"].Visible = false;
        }
```

(being that the `["Original Index"]` column represents a fixed index I want hidden.)

I've found the code on how to keep it as the first in the scroll list (if that makes sense), but can't make it selected and ready to use, it always defaults to the first cell of the first row.

How can I do this?

Comment: You are not refreshing the datasource at all - you are **re**setting it -- in effect using a new datasource. Proper refreshing using your dataadpater will retain selections

Comment: I just made an edit, not sure if that mistake matters to the new data source issue, but I always reset it with the same DataTable (dt). How exactly can I refresh though, then? @NewContributor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CurrentCell property for what you are trying to accomplish I believe.

Here is a similar issue already solved. 
[Datagridview: How to set a cell in editing mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814423/datagridview-how-to-set-a-cell-in-editing-mode)

if you have issues with the BeginEdit function try:

```
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;
```

I hope any of this helps.