# Modifying cell in binded DataGridView results in reverting to current value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a winform `DataGridView` binded to a typed `BindingSource`, itself binded to a DTO whose fields are read/write strings.

In my controller, I do `View.ItemDtoBindingSource.DataSource = FoundResults` where `FoundResults` is a `List<ItemDto>`, and the data grid displays the expected values.

I want to allow the user to make changes and expect that the `BindingSource` will update as the user changes cell values. Then an `Update` button will fetch the contents of `View.ItemDtoBindingSource` and make the desired changes in the back end.

I am not sure if I misunderstand the subtleties of data binding, but when I click on a cell on the data grid I am able to edit the value, but if I click away or press enter, the cursor leaves the cell and the value returns back to what it was before I tried to edit it (a behaviour expected if for example I had pressed Escape). Any reasons for this to happen?

I read that ReadOnly collections as a binding source may prevent from editing the datagrid, so I made sure I passed an `IList<T>` instead of an `IEnumerable<T>`, but this did not resolve the problem. I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729859/unable-to-edit-cell-in-datagridview) and made sure `VirtualMode = False`.

Comment: If you are using a `BindingSource` as a `DataSource` to the grid… then what construct are you using as a `DataSource` to the `BindingSource`? What is a `View`? How is the `ItemDto` object defined?

Comment: The BindingSource uses a List<T> . View is a winform which contains the DataGridView and the ItemDtoBindingSource. ItemDto is a POCO with 3 properties.

Comment: Post your `ItemDto` and whatever returns `FoundResults`.

Comment: I believe I have found the problem: `ItemDto` is a structure. Turning it into a class seems to work. I will run final tests and post an answer.

Comment: There's not much to test. Turn the struct into a class; use Properties, not Fields.

Answer (score 0):

When one of the rows in a `DataGridView` changes, the control updates the `BindingSource` by updating the item provided by the `DataSource`. The control updates the property of the existing item, it does not replace the existing item (to update) by a new one (updated).

Hence it is necessary to use classes instead of structure types as the generic type of the collection backing the `DataSource`. If not, then the control gets a copy (instead of a reference) of the item to update, updates the copy, then fetches the `DataSource` again but since it has not changed (only the copy has changed) the change is not reflected and is lost.